# What type of public/private key pair need to be used in yodlee?

Tags: yodlee

In `yodlee` development, we are asked to upload a public key. What is the required type of the keys as all types that `PuTTY Key Generator` can generate.

If anyone know, please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to generate an RSA key pair in the PKCS#8 format, using a key size of 2048 bits.

Comment: And I found that `openssl `works perfectly to generate key pairs.